# css animation transform - keep arbitrary rotation

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a CSS animation, for example, like this:

```
@keyframes my-animation {
    0%   { opacity: 0; visibility: visible; transform: scale(0,0); }
    50%  { transform: scale(1.15, 1.15); }
    100% { transform: none; }
}
```

And I want to apply it to a `DIV` that has an arbitrary rotation e.g. like this:

```
<div style="width:100px; height:100px; transform: rotate(45deg)"/>
```

When I apply the CSS `animation`, keyframes have another `transform` attribute that only sets `scale`. As a result, my `DIV` is rotated back to 0 during the animation and, at the end, it is restored back to 45 degree rotation.
But I want it to keep its arbitrary original rotation. So the question is: is there a way to specify in `transform` property of the keyframes that it should keep existing (arbitrary) rotation?

Something like `transform: scale(1.15, 1.15) rotate(keep)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS variables

```css
.x {
  transform: rotate(var(--r,0deg));
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display:inline-block;
  background: green;
  animation: my-animation 5s;
  margin: 20px;
}

@keyframes my-animation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0) rotate(var(--r,0deg));
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.15) rotate(var(--r,0deg));
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="x" style="--r:80deg"></div>

<div class="x" ></div>

<div class="x" style="--r:60deg"></div>
```

Or like below so you can append any transformation to the one defined in the keyframes

```css
:root {
  --r: rotate(0deg); /* Use any null transform (ex: translate(0), skew(0deg), etc)*/
}

.x {
  transform: var(--r);
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display:inline-block;
  background: green;
  animation: my-animation 5s;
  margin: 20px;
}

@keyframes my-animation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0) var(--r);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.15) var(--r);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="x" style="--r:rotate(80deg) skew(20deg)"></div>

<div class="x" ></div>

<div class="x" style="--r:rotate(60deg) translate(20px,20px)"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about css vars.

Answer (score -2):

Here's a simple solution without variables - I would just wrap your div and do the scaling on the wrapper, keeping the inner div rotated arbitrarily. Trivial, but does the trick I think.

```css
.box {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: green;
  margin: 50px;
}

.scale-me {
  animation: my-animation;
  animation-duration: 10s;
}

@keyframes my-animation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.15);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="scale-me">
  <div class="box" style="transform: rotate(45deg)"></div>
  <div class="box" style="transform: rotate(60deg)"></div>
  <div class="box" style="transform: rotate(120deg)"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is useful if you can't use CSS variables or don't wish to. Answers the question.